# This use of python ternary operator fails - not sure why?

Tags: python

In my function, if a dictionary exists (passed in as a parameter) then add another dictionary to it, or else use it as the dictionary.  (here context is the relevant dictionary)

```
def some_view(request, form_class, template, success_url, context=None):
    ..........
    if context is not None:
        context.update({'form': form})
    else:
        context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

This works fine but using

```
context = context.update({'form': form}) if context is not None else {'form': form}
```

fails for some reason as context is return as None?

Comment: If `context` is None, how can you call `update` on it?

Comment: `context.update()` returns `None` but you're using it in an assignment

Comment: This is because when you update an dictionary in python, it does not return anything. The update happens inplace.

Comment: Thanks that's the issue, it updated in place so doesn't return anything, so can't be used for an assignment.  I was thinking of it like evaluating an expression, so context could be assigned to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idiom you are looking for is simply

```
if context is None:
    context = {}
context.update({'form': form})
```

Comment: `context = context or {}` is even shorter (even though not exactly the same).

Comment: I prefer to be explicit.